# issues viewing git information with an unknown option message in the terminal

Tags: shell

while running the command 
"$ ls -al -/.ssh" in my terminal I get the message

"ls: unknown option -- /
Try 'ls --help' for more information."

Comment: you mean ~/.ssh ?

Comment: thanks a lot, I thought I tried this earlier and did not work. Thanks so much, that did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you messed up `-` and `~`

try

```
$ ls -al ~/.ssh
```